# Confirm if Ddos attack and how to block ip using django and apache http.conf

Tags: python, django, apache, security

**UPDATE**
I've edited the conf file to this but the ip's are still hitting the server, we are hosted on a webfaction shared server.

```
  ServerRoot "/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/apache2"

  LoadModule dir_module        modules/mod_dir.so
  LoadModule env_module        modules/mod_env.so
  LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
  LoadModule mime_module       modules/mod_mime.so
  LoadModule rewrite_module    modules/mod_rewrite.so
  LoadModule setenvif_module   modules/mod_setenvif.so
  LoadModule wsgi_module       modules/mod_wsgi.so
  LoadModule alias_module      modules/mod_alias.so
  LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
  LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so

  LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
  CustomLog /home/kbuzz/logs/user/access_django.log combined
  ErrorLog /home/kbuzz/logs/user/error_django.log
  KeepAlive Off
  Listen 23026
  MaxSpareThreads 3

  MinSpareThreads 1
  ServerLimit 1
  SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-SSL on HTTPS=1
  ThreadsPerChild 5
  WSGIDaemonProcess django processes=2 threads=8 python-path=/home/kbuzz/webapps/django:/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/kb:/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/lib/python2.7
  WSGIProcessGroup django
  WSGIRestrictEmbedded On
  WSGILazyInitialization On
  WSGIPassAuthorization On
  WSGIScriptAlias / /home/kbuzz/webapps/django/kb/kb/wsgi.py

  # "xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx" is a regular expression.
  # You can modify it to allow multiple IPs, ranges of IPs, etc.
  SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For 85\.130\.111\.126 blocked
  SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For 62\.210\.148\.246 blocked
  SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For 46\.4\.32\.75 blocked

  <Location "/">
   Order Allow,Deny
   Allow from all
   Deny from env=blocked
  </Location>


  <Location "/robots.txt">
      SetHandler None
  </Location>
  alias /robots.txt /home/kbuzz/webapps/kbuzz_static/kb/robots.txt

  <Location "/favicon.ico">
      SetHandler None
  </Location>
  alias /favicon.ico /home/kbuzz/webapps/kbuzz_static/kb/favicon.ico

  <Location "/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png">
      SetHandler None
  </Location>
  alias /apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png /home/kbuzz/webapps/kbuzz_static/kb/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png

  <Location "/apple-touch-icon.png">
      SetHandler None
  </Location>
  alias /apple-touch-icon.png /home/kbuzz/webapps/kbuzz_static/kb/apple-touch-icon.png

  <Location "/crossdomain.xml">
      SetHandler None
  </Location>
  alias /crossdomain.xml /home/kbuzz/webapps/kbuzz_static/kb/crossdomain.xml

  <Location "/sitemap.xml">
      SetHandler None
  </Location>
  alias /sitemap.xml /home/kbuzz/webapps/kbuzz_static/kb/sitemap.xml

  <Location "/sitemap.xml.gz">
      SetHandler None
  </Location>
  alias /sitemap.xml.gz /home/kbuzz/webapps/kbuzz_static/kb/sitemap.xml.gz

  <Location "/wordofmouth.php">
      Header always unset "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
      Header always unset "X-Frame-Options"
      Header always set "X-Frame-Options=ALLOW-ALL" "jsfiddle.net"
  </Location>

  <IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on

  # Perhaps better to whitelist expires rules? Perhaps.
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"

  # cache.appcache needs re-requests in FF 3.6 (thanks Remy ~Introducing HTML5)
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest "access plus 0 seconds"

  # Your document html
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 seconds"

  # Data
    ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 0 seconds"

  # Feed
    ExpiresByType application/rss+xml "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/atom+xml "access plus 1 hour"

  # Favicon (cannot be renamed)
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 week"

  # Media: images, video, audio
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 month"

  # HTC files (css3pie)
    ExpiresByType text/x-component "access plus 1 month"

  # Webfonts
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"

  # CSS and JavaScript
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"

    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      Header append Cache-Control "public"
    </IfModule>

  </IfModule>
```

I've been checking to see why my site is goes down after a few minutes after restarting. I've found this ip 85.130.111.126 in the netstat using `netstat -an | grep :80 | sort` according to http://www.abuseipdb.com/report-history/85.130.111.126 is suspected of ddos attack here's a dump of my result.

The three ips that have been making many attacks are

```
85.130.111.126
62.210.148.246
46.4.32.75
```

Each of them has been marked for Ddos attack, I want to block them but don't know how to do so with Django 1.5 running on apache's htppd.conf file.

```
ServerRoot "/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/apache2"

LoadModule dir_module        modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule env_module        modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module       modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule rewrite_module    modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module   modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule wsgi_module       modules/mod_wsgi.so
LoadModule alias_module      modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so

LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
CustomLog /home/kbuzz/logs/user/access_django.log combined
ErrorLog /home/kbuzz/logs/user/error_django.log
KeepAlive Off
Listen 23026
MaxSpareThreads 3

MinSpareThreads 1
ServerLimit 1
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-SSL on HTTPS=1
ThreadsPerChild 5
WSGIDaemonProcess django processes=2 threads=8 python-path=/home/kbuzz/webapps/django:/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/kb:/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/lib/python2.7
WSGIProcessGroup django
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On
WSGILazyInitialization On
WSGIPassAuthorization On
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/kbuzz/webapps/django/kb/kb/wsgi.py

<Location "/robots.txt">
    SetHandler None
</Location>
alias /robots.txt /home/kbuzz/webapps/kbuzz_static/kb/robots.txt

<Location "/favicon.ico">
    SetHandler None
</Location>
alias /favicon.ico /home/kbuzz/webapps/kbuzz_static/kb/favicon.ico

<Location "/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png">
    SetHandler None
</Location>
alias /apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png /home/kbuzz/webapps/kbuzz_static/kb/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png

<Location "/apple-touch-icon.png">
    SetHandler None
</Location>
alias /apple-touch-icon.png /home/kbuzz/webapps/kbuzz_static/kb/apple-touch-icon.png

<Location "/crossdomain.xml">
    SetHandler None
</Location>
alias /crossdomain.xml /home/kbuzz/webapps/kbuzz_static/kb/crossdomain.xml

<Location "/sitemap.xml">
    SetHandler None
</Location>
alias /sitemap.xml /home/kbuzz/webapps/kbuzz_static/kb/sitemap.xml

<Location "/sitemap.xml.gz">
    SetHandler None
</Location>
alias /sitemap.xml.gz /home/kbuzz/webapps/kbuzz_static/kb/sitemap.xml.gz

<Location "/wordofmouth.php">
    Header always unset "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
    Header always unset "X-Frame-Options"
    Header always set "X-Frame-Options=ALLOW-ALL" "jsfiddle.net"
</Location>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on

# Perhaps better to whitelist expires rules? Perhaps.
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"

# cache.appcache needs re-requests in FF 3.6 (thanks Remy ~Introducing HTML5)
  ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest "access plus 0 seconds"

# Your document html
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 seconds"

# Data
  ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 0 seconds"

# Feed
  ExpiresByType application/rss+xml "access plus 1 hour"
  ExpiresByType application/atom+xml "access plus 1 hour"

# Favicon (cannot be renamed)
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 week"

# Media: images, video, audio
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 month"

# HTC files (css3pie)
  ExpiresByType text/x-component "access plus 1 month"

# Webfonts
  ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"

# CSS and JavaScript
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"

  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Cache-Control "public"
  </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

Here's the dump below.

```
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.210.148.246:43449 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.210.148.246:43453 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.210.148.246:44363 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.210.148.246:44575 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.210.148.246:44682 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.210.148.246:45531 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.210.148.246:45659 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.210.148.246:45988 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.210.148.246:47068 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.210.148.246:47075 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.210.148.246:47171 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.210.148.246:48210 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.210.148.246:48323 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.210.148.246:48559 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.210.148.246:49359 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.210.148.246:49619 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.210.148.246:50040 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.210.148.246:50117 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.210.148.246:51254 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.210.148.246:51447 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.210.148.246:51697 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.210.148.246:52395 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.210.148.246:52953 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.210.148.246:53068 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.210.148.246:53693 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.210.148.246:54349 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.210.148.246:54753 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.210.148.246:55511 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.210.148.246:55966 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.210.148.246:56744 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.210.148.246:57277 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.210.148.246:58089 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.210.148.246:58339 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.210.148.246:59294 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.210.148.246:59371 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.210.148.246:60126 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.210.148.246:60440 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.210.148.246:60642 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.4.55.193:49602 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.97.71.90:10204 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.97.71.90:28410 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.97.71.90:54191 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.97.71.90:55386 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.97.71.90:7553 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 62.97.71.90:7836 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 65.55.210.49:43010 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 65.55.210.49:43058 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 66.220.156.104:57592 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 66.220.156.122:47355 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 66.220.156.96:49026 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 66.220.156.98:43633 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 66.249.64.224:42320 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 66.249.64.22:57634 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 66.249.64.229:57185 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 66.249.64.233:46469 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 66.249.64.233:56140 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 66.249.64.233:58013 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 66.249.64.249:35896 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 66.249.64.8:37671 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 66.249.81.244:64460 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 66.249.84.101:46602 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 66.249.84.175:46562 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 66.249.84.176:49618 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 66.249.89.117:40367 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 66.249.89.18:33038 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 66.35.32.1:2126 FIN_WAIT2
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 66.35.32.1:27732 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 66.35.32.1:5632 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 68.180.228.151:34307 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 68.180.228.151:36286 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 68.180.228.151:53903 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 68.180.228.151:54588 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 68.180.228.151:55933 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 68.180.228.225:39414 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 68.180.228.225:41160 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 68.180.228.225:48549 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 68.180.229.104:34880 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 68.180.229.104:34940 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 68.180.229.104:36582 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 68.180.229.104:38084 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 68.180.229.104:50961 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 68.180.229.104:51824 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 68.180.229.29:52253 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 68.180.229.46:38137 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 68.180.229.46:57959 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 68.180.229.46:59489 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 68.180.229.46:60253 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 68.180.230.105:49898 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 69.191.249.215:12433 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 69.30.214.38:45095 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 69.39.158.162:16070 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 69.39.158.162:59894 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 69.58.50.130:51906 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 74.108.45.233:64180 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 74.50.105.205:63428 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 74.50.105.205:63451 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 77.34.235.165:18465 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 78.186.152.133:53418 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 78.186.152.133:53419 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 78.186.152.133:53420 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 78.56.64.207:3412 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 79.141.221.244:53023 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 79.141.221.244:53027 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 79.141.221.244:53028 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 79.141.221.244:53029 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 79.141.221.244:53030 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 79.141.221.244:53031 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 79.168.12.174:52571 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 79.168.12.174:52572 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 79.77.173.144:57859 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 79.77.173.144:57860 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 79.77.173.144:57861 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 79.77.173.144:57862 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 79.77.173.144:57863 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 79.77.173.144:57864 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 80.229.228.73:64213 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 80.229.228.73:64214 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 80.229.228.73:64215 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 80.229.228.73:64217 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 80.229.228.73:64218 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 80.229.228.73:64221 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 80.229.228.73:64222 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 80.229.228.73:64223 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 80.229.228.73:64224 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 80.229.228.73:64225 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 80.229.228.73:64226 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 80.229.228.73:64227 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 80.229.228.73:64228 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 80.229.228.73:64229 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 81.151.73.233:49752 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 81.151.73.233:49753 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 81.151.73.233:49755 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 82.145.220.79:35400 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 83.220.239.86:3560 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 83.240.217.177:50163 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 83.240.217.177:50164 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 83.92.61.122:50766 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 83.92.61.122:50767 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 83.92.61.122:50768 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 84.163.76.134:55485 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 84.242.216.65:50768 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:33292 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:33310 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:33817 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:34433 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:34454 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:34471 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:34492 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:34506 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:34524 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:35459 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:35940 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:35956 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:35987 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:36599 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:36618 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:36642 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:37564 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:37583 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:37600 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:37615 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:37638 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:37656 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:37680 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:38251 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:38576 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:38605 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:38620 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:38642 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:38661 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:38970 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:38989 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:39014 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:39037 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:39057 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:39076 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:40038 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:40072 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:40855 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:40873 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:40895 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:41384 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:41423 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:41988 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:42002 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:42025 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:42049 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:42063 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:42604 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:43188 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:43371 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:43392 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:43835 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:43860 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:44011 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:44031 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:44048 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:44063 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:44207 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:44229 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:44252 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:44773 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:44791 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:44813 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:44936 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:45051 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:45999 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:46030 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:46050 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:46069 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:46088 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:46217 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:46233 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:47175 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:47193 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:47286 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:47305 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:47330 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:47342 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:47371 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:47388 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:47492 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:47602 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:48185 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:48256 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:48274 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:48289 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:48304 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:48323 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:48360 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:48781 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:49322 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:49339 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:49352 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:49372 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:49399 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:49946 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:50029 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:50052 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:50072 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:50654 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:50681 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:50731 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:50749 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:50815 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:50843 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:50864 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:50950 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:50967 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:51002 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:51185 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:51265 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:51286 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:51304 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:51333 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:51357 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:51377 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:51399 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:51423 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:51444 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:51820 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:51841 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:51857 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:52017 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:52532 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:52552 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:52572 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:52587 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:52607 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:53157 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 86.18.154.211:60337 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 86.18.154.211:60338 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 86.18.154.211:60339 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 86.18.154.211:60340 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 86.18.154.211:60341 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 86.18.154.211:60345 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 86.18.154.211:60359 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 86.18.154.211:60360 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 86.18.154.211:60362 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 87.213.170.193:58646 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 89.180.216.246:52467 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 89.180.216.246:52469 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 89.180.216.246:52476 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 89.180.216.246:52478 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 89.211.154.96:14087 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 89.216.16.226:51936 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 89.216.16.226:51942 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 89.216.16.226:51962 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 89.216.16.226:51963 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 89.216.16.226:51964 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 89.216.16.226:51965 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 89.216.16.226:51966 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 89.216.16.226:51967 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 89.216.16.226:51968 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 89.216.16.226:51969 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 89.216.16.226:51970 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 89.216.16.226:51971 FIN_WAIT2
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 94.138.42.219:48870 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 94.228.34.249:51410 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 94.228.34.249:61325 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 94.51.232.139:59404 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 5.153.9.51:80 95.105.151.190:30097 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 1003648 127.0.0.1:80 127.0.0.1:53459 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 13011 5.153.9.51:80 2.26.41.226:62098 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 13909 5.153.9.51:80 14.120.162.193:6517 FIN_WAIT1
tcp 0 1 5.153.9.51:80 162.219.29.103:60535 FIN_WAIT1
tcp 0 185722 127.0.0.1:80 127.0.0.1:54396 FIN_WAIT1
tcp 0 1961 5.153.9.51:80 49.15.86.238:21961 FIN_WAIT1
tcp 0 217 5.153.9.51:80 5.102.254.169:14263 FIN_WAIT1
tcp 0 217 5.153.9.51:80 5.102.254.169:14266 FIN_WAIT1
tcp 0 24616 5.153.9.51:80 68.205.83.21:55926 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 312 5.153.9.51:80 85.130.111.126:53183 FIN_WAIT1
tcp 0 33556 5.153.9.51:80 83.238.231.103:1240 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 40320 5.153.9.51:80 27.16.170.7:23428 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 4914 127.0.0.1:80 127.0.0.1:54391 FIN_WAIT1
tcp 0 505350 127.0.0.1:80 127.0.0.1:52458 FIN_WAIT1
tcp 0 52128 5.153.9.51:80 83.238.231.103:1241 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 52128 5.153.9.51:80 83.238.231.103:1243 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 5242 5.153.9.51:80 49.15.86.238:62611 FIN_WAIT1
tcp 0 531 5.153.9.51:80 14.120.162.193:6179 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 68056 5.153.9.51:80 83.238.231.103:1239 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 950272 127.0.0.1:80 127.0.0.1:53445 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 98464 5.153.9.51:80 192.3.247.133:47731 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 98464 5.153.9.51:80 23.94.66.109:59969 ESTABLISHED
tcp 1 0 127.0.0.1:80 127.0.0.1:54386 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp 1 0 127.0.0.1:8069 127.0.0.1:52721 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp 1 1 5.153.9.51:80 117.102.48.71:51541 CLOSING
tcp 1 16177 5.153.9.51:80 105.231.148.30:1078 LAST_ACK
tcp 1 16177 5.153.9.51:80 105.231.148.30:1083 LAST_ACK
tcp 1 16177 5.153.9.51:80 105.231.148.30:1100 LAST_ACK
tcp 1 28309 5.153.9.51:80 105.231.148.30:1095 LAST_ACK
tcp 156800 0 127.0.0.1:53445 127.0.0.1:80 ESTABLISHED
tcp 157312 0 127.0.0.1:53459 127.0.0.1:80 ESTABLISHED
tcp 163840 0 127.0.0.1:54391 127.0.0.1:80 ESTABLISHED
tcp 29153 0 127.0.0.1:54382 127.0.0.1:80 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp 326648 0 127.0.0.1:52458 127.0.0.1:80 ESTABLISHED
```

Comment: You'll probably want iptables to filter them if it's installed, instead of apache. Try something like `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 85.130.111.126 --dport http -j REJECT ; iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport http -j ACCEPT` (caution: not tested)

Comment: I'm hosted on webfaction and when I run the command it replies only root can run the command. @SimonFraser

Comment: While I see this going either way and therefore won't vote to move, you might consider moving this to serverfault.

Comment: I second Frank that this is a serverfault question in future. However given your situation, I've posted the info you need as an answer this time. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To block those IP's with apache [mod_authz_host](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html) use the following in your config:

```
<Directory /home/kbuzz/webapps/django/apache2>
    order allow,deny
    deny from 85.130.111.126
    deny from 62.210.148.246
    deny from 46.4.32.75
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

The requests will still hit apache which will respond with a 403 forbidden header.